# How to change whole div background with hover

Tags: html, css, hover

How can I change the background of my div `interestBTN` with css?

My css:

```
.interestBTN {
  width: 50%;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-color: #ACED52;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #ACED52;
}

div.interestBTN :hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ACED52;

}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><div class="interestBTN"><strong>Open</strong></div></a>
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: remove the space before the colon

Comment: remove the space before the `:hover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the space before the `:hover`

```css
.interestBTN {
  width: 50%;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-color: #ACED52;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #ACED52;
}

div.interestBTN:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ACED52;

}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="interestBTN"><strong>Open</strong></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.interestBTN {
  width: 50%;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-color: #ACED52;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #ACED52;
}

div.interestBTN:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ACED52;

}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="interestBTN"><strong>Open</strong></div></a>
```